# How much time does it take friction to start acting?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

I was wondering whether friction has some particular timing when it starts to act, like does it start instantaneously or does it take some time to start applying force on that particular object.

Comment: Are you asking with regard to static or kinetic friction?

Comment: If you have two objects in contact, it never stops acting.

Answer (score 1):

Since friction occurs due to the irregularities on the surface of materials where between two bodies when these irregularities "bumps" meet, charged particles get very close to each other and exert electromagnetic force (attractive) note: $F_{EM} \sim 1/r^2$, magnitude of the EM force increases as the distance between charged particles get smaller.

So it could be partially said that it's due to electromagnetic force, and it travels at the speed of light. So it's not instantaneous.